# horizontal scrolling for item divs confined to a larger div

Tags: html, css, scroll

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/7zk1bbs2/

If you look at the jsfiddle product you ll see the icons are fitted in an orange box. However, you have to scroll vertically to search through them and im trying to scroll horizontally. How do i do this?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<HTML>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> My Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="banner">   
        <h1> Welcome!<span style="color:#FF009D" class="dot">•‌</span><span style="color:#12E00B" class="dot">•‌</span><span style="color:#FF9D00" class="dot">•‌</span> </h1>
    </div>
            <div class="wrap"> 
                    <div class="item">    
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/maxxchewning">
                            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/HrkZQ3EOmFQ/hqdefault.jpg"/>
                                <div class="button"></div>
                        </a>    
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/Christianguzmanfitne">
                            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/zsD_7hkfEwY/hqdefault.jpg"/>
                            <div class="button"></div>
                        </a>         
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/PhysiquesOfGreatness">
                            <img src="http://v017o.popscreen.com/VzFBeVBjMHhpRWMx_o_new-physiques-of-greatness-intro-25.jpg"/>
                            <div class="button"></div>
                        </a>     
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">    
                        <a href="https://www.reddit.com">
                            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/459083822470946816/VGv0AGio.png"/>
                                <div class="button"></div>
                        </a>    
                   </div>
                   <div class="item">    
                        <a href="https://www.ebay.com">
                            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/471350614132129793/NCDCFXva.jpeg"/>
                                <div class="button"></div>
                        </a>    
                   </div>
                    <div class="item">    
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
                            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3513354941/24aaffa670e634a7da9a087bfa83abe6_400x400.png"/>
                                <div class="button"></div>
                        </a>    
                   </div>  
            </div>

    <div class="footer"></footer>
</body>

</HTML>
```

CSS

```
body {       
        margin-top:-3px;
}
.banner {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color: rgba(64, 201, 255, 1);
    margin-left:-10px;
}

h1 { 
    font-size:80px;
    margin-left:30px;
    font-family:Futura;
    line-height:120px;
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    width:100%;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    padding-top:30px;

}


h1:hover { 
    font-size:80px;
    font-family:Futura;
    color: rgba(64, 201, 255,.8);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255,0.9);
    width:100%;
    padding-top:30px;
}

.wrap{ 
    margin-top:20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 190, 77, 1);
    height:200px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    overflow:auto;
}


.item {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;


}

.item img {
    width:100%;
    padding-top:10px;
    max-height:100px;
    opacity:1;
}
.item img:hover {
    opacity:.4;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform:    scale(1.2);
    -o-transform:      scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform:     scale(1.2);
}

.button {
    background-color:rgba(64, 201, 255,1);
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:.5em;
    border-bottom-left-radius:.5em;    
    transition: background-color 0.3s linear;     
}
.item:hover .button{
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 157, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform:    scale(1.2);
    -o-transform:      scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform:     scale(1.2);

}
```

Comment: Width of container `wrap` should be equal to sum of items' width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you change your .wrap class overflow with

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

and change your .item class float with

```
display: inline-block;
```

.wrap and item final look like this

```
.wrap{ 
    margin-top:20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 190, 77, 1);
    height:200px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width:25%;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

May be your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

## With little tweaks you can do this check the updated fiddle

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/7zk1bbs2/5/)

```
 .wrap-in { width:2000px; }
 .item {width:200px}
 .wrap{overflow:hidden;overflow-x:scroll;width:960px}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your h1 is bleeding past the `.banner`. (in particular, the margin-left on the h1 is causing the page to get a horizontal scroll)

**Two solutions:**

**Have the .banner hide anything beyond its bounding box**(http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/7zk1bbs2/3/)

```
.banner {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

It kind of looks ugly without additional styling...

**Remove the left-margin from the h1** (http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/7zk1bbs2/2/)

```
h1 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

But with this, you lose the padding you were attempting.

**Or a combination of the above** (I cleaned up the code a little):

http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/7zk1bbs2/4/

Also, as minor css improvement for your fiddle, when using `{selector}:hover`, you only need to add the css styles that you want changed, you don't have to redefine what already exists with `{selector}`.